# A metric space $(\Bbb R,d)$ with $d(x,y)=||x-y||$ is complete!

Tags: metric-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I would like to receive only the hint, how to prove the statement on the heading.
I understand that we have to prove that all Cauchy sequences converges in the space $\Bbb R$, e.g.
$$\lim_{p,q\rightarrow+\infty}||x_p-x_q||=0\Longrightarrow \exists\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}x_n\in \Bbb R.$$

Comment: It would help to know how $\mathbb R$ is constructed - there are various ways of doing it which turn out to be equivalent - but the construction or definition used affects what can be assumed in the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Every sequence in $R$ contains a monotonic subsequence.